# Vue – access JSON data in method

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to write a simple function in the methods. It should create an array out of JSON data.

The JSON object is called `page` with another object called `images` containing height, orientation etc.

```
setup () {
   return {
     page: usePage(),
   }
},

methods: {
   getOrientations() {
      this.page.images.forEach((item) => {
      console.log(item
  })
}
```

Unfortunately it throws an `undefined is not an object` error. Logging only `this.page` however prints the whole object.

Does `this.page.images` not work when using it inside a method? Because it works when using it "inline" in HTML.

Thanks for any tips!

Comment: What is `setup`? I never saw this in Vue. It should be `data` instead.

Comment: It's new in Vue 3

Answer (score 3):

You are currently using the [Composition API](https://composition-api.vuejs.org/) (`setup` function) alongside the options-based API (`methods` object). Although it is possible, it is not recommended (take a look at their [motivation](https://composition-api.vuejs.org/#motivation)). Your methods should stand in the `setup` function:

```js
setup () {
  const page = usePage()
  page.images.forEach((item) => {
    console.log(item)
  })
  return {
    page,
  }
},
```

Of course, you could still modularize this code using functions.

```js
setup() {
  // ...
  const getOrientations = () => {
    page.images.forEach((item) => {
      console.log(item)
    })
  }

  // And make it available to your template
  return {
    // ...
    getOrientations
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi! Ah ok, thanks for the insight! Is there a reason why the console now prints the actual code of the variable? Sorry, I'm kind of new to maybe complicated JS, maybe this is a silly question.

Comment: Unfortunately the error 'TypeError: undefined is not an object' persists even with the changed setup function

Comment: Then I think your error is not related to this problem. Could you copy the full stacktrace?